# polymer google map marker infoWindow content not showing

Tags: google-maps, polymer, web-component

I´m trying to show some info using the attribute content inside an infoWindow for a google map marker, like this:

`<google-map-info content="{{marker.latLonTs.ts}}"></google-map-info>`

but nothing is displayed, I managed to show it using this code:

```
<google-map-info >
     <p>{{marker.latLonTs.ts}}</p>
</google-map-info>
```

but when marker.latLonts.ts is updated, nothing happend, I think the correct way to do the binding is using the content attribute, but I should be missing something. Is there any other polymer element that I could use instead of `<p></p>` to try to bind the info properly? Thanks

Added code:

```
<google-map  zoom="6"  id="google_global_map" >
            <template repeat="{{marker in markers}}">   

                <google-map-marker id="google_global_map_marker" 
                    latitude="{{marker.latLonTs.lat}}" 
                    longitude="{{marker.latLonTs.lon}}" 
                    title="{{marker.nombre}}" 
                    icon="{{marker.latLonTs.icon}}">
                        <google-map-info >

                        <p>{{marker.latLonTs.ts}}</p>
                        </google-map-info>
                </google-map-marker>

            </template>
            </google-map>

<script>
Polymer('post-listMap',{

urlMap : [],
urlMapCacheUpdate : "http://m/sondas_map/cache/",
urlGetMapCache: "http://m/sondas_map/getCache/",
request : false,
requestCache: false,
ready: function(){

},
reqMapCache: function(){
    if(this.requestCache==false){

        this.$.ajaxGetMapCache.go();
        console.log('Cargando ubicaciones en cache...');
        this.requestCache = true;
    }


},

mapLoadCache: function(){

this.markersCache = this.$.ajaxGetMapCache.response;


        this.markers = this.markersCache;
        this.$.google_global_map.resize();
        this.$.google_global_map.latitude = 40.415349;
        this.$.google_global_map.longitude = -3.784403;
        document.querySelector('post-listMap').reqMap();
},

reqMap: function() {

    this.urlMap = "http://m/sondas_map/";

    this.$.ajaxMap.go();
    console.log('Cargando ubicaciones reales...');

},
mapLoad: function(){

    var tempMarkers = this.$.ajaxMap.response;
    this.markers = null;


    this.markers = this.markersCache;

    tempMarkers = JSON.stringify(tempMarkers);
    this.$.ajaxMapCacheUpdate.body = tempMarkers;

    this.$.ajaxMapCacheUpdate.go();

  }


 });
</script>
```

Comment: You'll need to post more code so we can see what your element definition looks like. Check that `content` is a published property if you're going to use it as an attribute like that. Also, have you see http://googlewebcomponents.github.io/google-map/components/google-map/? It supports info window content has HTML children of `<google-map-maker>`.

Comment: Thanks, ebidel! There's the code. First time I set the attribute markers, the info is loaded in the window, but the second time I trie, inside the function mapLoad(), the info stays as it was. For the lat and lon attributes of the markers the binding works both times, thats why I thought using content as an attribute could solve the problem.